# Extjs - retry API request in Model.save()

Tags: javascript, extjs, callback, extjs4.1

Disclaimer: I am new to `extjs` and is still finding my way around the framework.

I have an `extjs` frontend that communicates with a PHP backend. A part of my application submits data to the backend and receives the response like so:

```
var data = {
    "name": values.namefield,
    "activityList" : validActivityList,
    "flag": true
};

var cluster = Ext.create('ClusterModel', data);

cluster.save({
    success: function (model,data) {
        //handle success scenario
    },
    failure: function (model, response) {
        //oops something went wrong
        //need to retry the request with data flag set to false!
    }
});
```

I have a particular failure scenario where I need to retry the request by setting the `flag` field to false. The only way I can think of doing this is by nesting and duplicating code within the failure handler.

Something like this:

```
failure: function (model, response) {
    //oops something went wrong
    //need to retry the request with data flag set to false!
    var data = {
        "name": values.namefield,
        "activityList" : validActivityList,
        "flag": false
    };

    var clusterRetry = Ext.create('ClusterModel', data);
    clusterRetry.save({...//more duplicate code})
}
```

This feels like a very bad idea and I'm not even sure if it will work. Is there any other option that would allow me to accomplish this?

also of note, I am using extjs 4.1.1

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function who call himself where she is on error with flag as false.

Something like that :

```
SaveCluster: function(values, validActivityList, flag) {
    var data = {
        "name": values.namefield,
        "activityList" : validActivityList,
        "flag": flag
    };

    var cluster = Ext.create('ClusterModel', data);

    cluster.save({
        success: function (model,data) {
            //handle success scenario
        },
        failure: function (model, response) {
            this.SaveCluster(values, validActivityList, false);
        }
    });
}
```

You can be have scope problem in failure function, i let you find a solution if the problem appear and feel free to ask us if you have trouble with it.

I start ExtJS 2 year ago and i remembre how this framework is brainfuck at the begin ;)